# Fill Null values of a query with value from specific row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a big query which results in the table below (summarized):

```
Rank | LockID | LockNumber | FirstInvoiceDate 

 1   |    1   |     800    | 2014-10-10      
 2   |    1   |     800    |   NULL
 3   |    2   |     800    |   NULL
 1   |    3   |     900    | 2015-12-10
 2   |    4   |     900    |   NULL
```

I want to make the last column as below:

```
| FirstInvoiceDate 

| 2014-10-10      
| 2014-10-10      
| 2014-10-10      
| 2015-12-10      
| 2015-12-10
```

i.e., Locks with the same number need to have the same FirstInvoiceDate

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an update.  SQL Server has the nice feature of updatable CTEs, so you can do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, min(FirstInvoiceDate) over (partition by LockNumber) as new_FID
      from table
)
update toupdate
    set FirstInvoiceDate = new_FID;
```

If you don't need the update, but just the value in a `select`, then you can use the expression in `toupdate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly fine (but there is a `partition by` needed before `LockNumber`), but it made the query super slow :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try a function called Lag to get value of previous row after you  check if value is NULL

```
SELECT ISNULL (LAG(T.FirstInvoiceDate) OVER (ORDER BY p.LockID) ) from yourTable T
```

for more details please refere to

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using SQL Server 2008 and can't use `LAG`